# SwiftUI Load single object JSON from URL

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, decode

I'm trying to use a single object JSON file stored on a website. I want to display one of the variables (spot) from the JSON file in the Text inside the ZStack. However there is a problem with defining the @State variable spotData. SwiftUI's Error: "Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call".
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct SpotStructure: Decodable {
    
    var spot: String
    var country_code: String
    var is_weather_station: Bool
    var month: [Int]
    var day: [Int]
    var weekday: [String]
    var hour: [Int]
    var current_wind: Int
    var current_wind_direction: Int
    var wind_speed: [Int]
    var wind_gusts: [Int]
    var wind_direction: [Int]
    var wave_height: [Double]
    var wave_period: [Int]
    var wave_direction: [Int]
    var weather_icon: [String]
    var current_temperature: Int
    var temperature: [Int]
    
    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }

    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var spotData = SpotStructure()
    
    func loadspotdata()  {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bene2907/Bene2907.github.io/master/brouwersdam.json") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(SpotStructure.self, from: data)
                        spotData = res
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{

            Text(spotData.spot)

        }.onAppear(perform: loadspotdata)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call - SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522114/missing-argument-for-parameter-from-in-call-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize the `struct` without puting all values (because of all variables are not optional `!`)

```
@State var spotData = SpotStructure(spot: <#T##String#>, country_code: <#T##String#>, is_weather_station: <#T##Bool#>, month: <#T##[Int]#>, day: <#T##[Int]#>, weekday: <#T##[String]#>, hour: <#T##[Int]#>, current_wind: <#T##Int#>, current_wind_direction: <#T##Int#>, wind_speed: <#T##[Int]#>, wind_gusts: <#T##[Int]#>, wind_direction: <#T##[Int]#>, wave_height: <#T##[Double]#>, wave_period: <#T##[Int]#>, wave_direction: <#T##[Int]#>, weather_icon: <#T##[String]#>, current_temperature: <#T##Int#>, temperature: <#T##[Int]#>, coordinates: <#T##Coordinates#>)
```

Or change your `struct` and make all variables optional

```
struct SpotStructure: Codable {
    var spot: String? = nil
    var country_code: String? = nil
    var is_weather_station: Bool? = nil
    var month: [Int]? = nil
    var day: [Int]? = nil
    var weekday: [String]? = nil
    var hour: [Int]? = nil
    var current_wind: Int? = nil
    var current_wind_direction: Int? = nil
    var wind_speed: [Int]? = nil
    var wind_gusts: [Int]? = nil
    var wind_direction: [Int]? = nil
    var wave_height: [Double]? = nil
    var wave_period: [Int]? = nil
    var wave_direction: [Int]? = nil
    var weather_icon: [String]? = nil
    var current_temperature: Int? = nil
    var temperature: [Int]? = nil
    
    var coordinates: Coordinates? = nil
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates!.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates!.longitude)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Been looking for this for hours.

Comment: Making everything optional is _not_ a good solution

Comment: Yes it’s not good , but he want to use an empty constructor , i given him the both possibilities